# Maven, how to run external Tomcat server

Tags: tomcat, maven, maven-tomcat-plugin

I have some issue, I can't solve.
I has unzipped tomcat server in D:/server/tomcat7 and I wanna to start it from maven, for future deploying my WebApp there. But I can't find how to configure external folder for running tomcat.

If I call in cmd mvn tomcat:run, maven will download tomcat and run it, but I need to start server from the folder, I specified above.

Tnx for answers

Answer (score 1):

You can try maven-exec-plugin to start/stop Tomcat by scripts from ${CATALINA_HOME}/bin:

```
  <plugin>  
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>  
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>  
    <version>1.1</version>  
    <executions>  
      <execution>  
        <id>stop-tomcat</id>  
        <phase>pre-clean</phase>  
        <goals>  
          <goal>exec</goal>  
        </goals>  
        <configuration>  
        <executable>${tomcat.stop.path}</executable>  
        </configuration>  
      </execution>  
      <execution>  
        <id>start-tomcat</id>  
        <phase>deploy</phase>  
        <goals>  
          <goal>exec</goal>  
        </goals>  
        <configuration>  
        <executable>${tomcat.start.path}</executable>    
        </configuration>  
      </execution>  
    </executions>  
  </plugin>
```

Comment: Ok, tnx. And could u provide with example of ${tomcat.stop.path}

Comment: The value of tomcat.stop.path should be absolute path to the stop script (here is possible example for Windows: C:\Progra~1\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-7.0.25\bin\startup.bat)

Comment: Better place to define the value of the Tomcat start/stop path properties is the properties section of the settings.xml file in the .m2 subdirectory of user home - to allow team members or build server admins easiest way to configure their values of paths

Answer (score 0):

Not possible but I wonder what is your use case ?
The goal of this plugin is to avoid such manual installation.